# Rename: [mfmessagecomposeview] to [mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller], and link with [messageui]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tag [mfmessagecomposeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mfmessagecomposeview) is about the iOS SDK class `MFMessageComposeViewController`, which is part of the Message UI Framework (the associated tag is [messageui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messageui)).

Therefore, I think the misspelled [mfmessagecomposeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mfmessagecomposeview) should be renamed into [mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller), and linked with the [messageui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messageui) tag.

Comment: Tag names [have a 25-character limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209248/increase-limit-on-tag-length).

Comment: oops, didn't aware the limit.

Comment: One of the benefits of waiting 7 years to get this implemented is that the 25-character limit is no more. Tag renamed and synonymized with the old one. :-)